# Trying to read data from old gadget with pylibftdi fails

Tags: python, ftdi, libftdi

I have a small USB device from Windows XP times. It receives a sea weather report on a special frequency and transmits it in text form. This requires a program and driver that only runs on Windows XP. (Old Page here: http://www.navichart.com/wettermaus.htm)

I would now like to try to get the device running with python3 under Linux in order to later turn it into a raspberry project.

The device is recognized by Linux:

lsusb results in:

```
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 0403: f9d9 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd NAVCODE weather mouse
```

I opened the Device and found some Chips on it: FTDI FT232BM, Atmel ATMEGA8L and some others, smaller ones.

For this reason I thought it might be possible to access the device with pylibfdti and read the weather report.

I proceeded here according to:
https://pylibftdi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

But if I try the following code I only get an empty list and nothing to print.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import pylibftdi
print(pylibftdi.Driver().list_devices())
```

Results in

```
[]
```

I checked in a VirtualBox running Windows XP: The old programm and the USB-Devive are working normal.

I have no experience with programming such chips and i have no other device to check wether i made an mistake.

Do I have a "mistake in my thoughts" and my project cannot work at all?

Thanks for your advice.
F.E.